# Random Walk on a Modified Binary Tree

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $T$ be an infinitely rooted binary tree. Let $\Gamma$ be the tree obtained from $T$ by replacing each edge whose verticies are at  distances $k$ and $k+1$ from the root by a chain of $2^k$ edges. Determine whether simple random walk on Γ is recurrent or transient.

I'm not too sure how to think of this. For a binary tree you consider a sequence of random variables corresponding to the level which has probability $\frac{2}{3}$ of moving down and $\frac{1}{3}$ of moving up. Do I still consider the levels here and invoke borel cantelli? It is difficult since the length of the chains are not constant

Comment: *Hint.* Now the probability of moving down and moving up between levels (defined for vertices of $T$, identified as subset of $\Gamma$) are equally $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Or, if the electric network theory is applicable, then assuming the unit resistance on each edge, the effective resistance from the root to $\infty$ on $\Gamma$ is computed as $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{3 \cdot 2^k} = \infty $, hence the random walk is recurrent.